# How to not editable mail composer in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I enable mail composer by using intent, it's go to native application. That's fine, my question is, am hardcore to, Cc, Subject and Body message, it's work fine, my problem is Body message is editable, So Is it possible to disable Body message(not editable) ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: you need to send the mail without user intervention.You need to use the link [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android).

Comment: ok,it's possible user can't editable the mail by using this intent,because i want to show the mail composer that's why i ask

Comment: Intent opens the inbuilt mail application and it is always editable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18151/discussion-between-vicky-and-appmobigurmeet)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.
Only if you write (or find) an email app that has a trigger for receiving intents with a certain flag in the extra data that makes that the body message uneditable. But I have never heard of any such email app.
The only other way is to directly send the email, but then you have to have all other fields set on beforehand.